# FilteredSelectMultiple Widget renders wrong url for image

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin

I'm using the django admin's FilteredSelectMultiple widget outside of the admin. I've followed a few guides and had this work in the past, but it's not correctly rendering the url for the gifs that are used for the icons (the magnifying glass and the small question marks next to the "available" and "chosen" titles)

The rendered url reads:

```
<img src="undefinedimg/selector-search.gif" class="help-tooltip" 
alt="" title="Type into this box to filter down the list of available 
Tags.">
```

So, it seems like there's some variable the template should be expecting, but I can't find in the code where/what it is. ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is defined in the settings and if I manually change the url to remove "undefined" and add that it works. Is there some other variable name it's expecting?